# Block IP/Domain (youtube.com, facebook) and other distracting sites connected via phone's hotspot

Tags: rooting, ads, hosts, filter

Is there a way to block youtube.com and other distracting site like facebook.com when my Laptop is connected via android hotspot at my phone's end i.e. blocking sites via android hosts file. After reading the following techrepublic article, makes me think it's possible but not sure so asking this question.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/edit-your-rooted-android-hosts-file-to-block-ad-servers/

To edit phones hosts file, android phone must be rooted so I want to be sure before rooting my phone,

If this is not the correct approach then what other options are available.

Thanks

Comment: See my answers to [How to Block/Filter Sites on Mobile Data Connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219405/218526) and [How to block access to a website?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218316/218526). It's already a widely discussed topic: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+block+websites